# Access file address of a particular file in Linux (lubuntu)

Tags: linux, shell

I am running a program that returns me address of the file. 
How am i able to access these file address through terminal in Linux?

Reason i am looking for the command line for terminal in linux is to compare it to the address.

Example

a.txt = D@39d56e9

b.txt = D@4eb4dcd9

and so on..

```
Example of output program
[[D@39d56e9, [D@4eb4dcd9, [D@440f52ed, [D@4a0d6883, [D@36489670, [D@578caee7, [D@552eec98, [D@7baf1ad8, [D@250b9a58, [D@1cc21a68, [D@b53b098, [D@236ed0f7]
```

Comment: That really looks like someone calling `toString()` on Java `double[]`(s).

Comment: yeah. the excuting program is in Java

Answer (score 0):

> yeah. the excuting program is in Java

Modify your executing Java program, it is building an array of primitive `double`(s) and `double []` doesn't override `toString()`. Easiest fix is probably to use [`Arrays.toString(double[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double[]%29) like

```
 // System.out.println(arr); // <--prints D[ and a 32-bit hashcode
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Is Arrays in this context an example of a class or its a syntax?

Comment: the arr that i am passing in is an object, is there any way to go by with it?
It returned me an error where there are other types of object that toString,(is not able to process)

Comment: Every array is an object, array doesn't override toString hence your output. Read the answer again.